# Create directory and write insite files

Tags: r

I have a script, written in R, that generate a lot of output. I would like to put these outputs into their own directories.  Then I would like to create, in R, a directory and then move into it, writing file inside it. Is there a way to approach this?

Comment: Yes, possible, but without more detail it is not possible to give a sensible answer.

Comment: Check this tutorial to learn how to manage the working directory, create, copy, list and remove files from a directory with code: https://r-coder.com/working-directory-r/

Answer (score -1):

Use `dir.create()` function. Link:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/files2